# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status. => Cors/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cors, axios

I am currently writing an application that speaks to an API thorugh an axios post req. in order to receive a response.

I have a .vue component, whose content is a form with given specs.
I installed CORS through the composer, set up my cors.php and added everything neccessary in my kernel.php.

My Vue is stored in a .blade. php view.

Everytime, when I try to send the data, I get this error message by cors:

> 'http://myurl//' from
>   origin 'http://api.laragon:8090' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It
>   does not have HTTP ok status.

The data is send through post as mentioned with a form, that runs this method when submit button is clicked:

```
formSubmit(e) {
 const url="x";

  e.preventDefault();

  let currentObj = this;
  this.axios
    .post(url, {
      age: this.age,

      claimantType: this.claimantType,
      // zipcode: this.zipcode,

      mcMax: 3,
      icdCount: 1,
      iCDCountInitialIllnesses: 0, //fix:0
      uniqueVisitedDoctorsCount: 1, //fix:1
      daysBetweenAccidentAndAC: 20, //fix:20
      daysInHospital: 0, //fix:0
      s13_4_only: 0 //fix:0 => 1, if only! selected
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      currentObj.output = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      currentObj.output = error;
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

/config/app.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value is the name of your application. This value is used when the
    | framework needs to place the application's name in a notification or
    | any other location as required by the application or its packages.
    |
    */

    'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Environment
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value determines the "environment" your application is currently
    | running in. This may determine how you prefer to configure various
    | services the application utilizes. Set this in your ".env" file.
    |
    */

    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Debug Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
    | stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
    | application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
    |
    */

    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
    | the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
    | your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
    |
    */

    'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),

    'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Timezone
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
    | will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
    | ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
    |
    */

    'timezone' => 'UTC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Locale Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
    | by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
    | to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
    |
    */

    'locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Fallback Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
    | is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
    | the language folders that are provided through your application.
    |
    */

    'fallback_locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Faker Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This locale will be used by the Faker PHP library when generating fake
    | data for your database seeds. For example, this will be used to get
    | localized telephone numbers, street address information and more.
    |
    */

    'faker_locale' => 'en_US',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Encryption Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
    | to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
    | will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
    |
    */

    'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Autoloaded Service Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
    | request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
    | this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
        Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class,


        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => [

        'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Arr' => Illuminate\Support\Arr::class,
        'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Broadcast' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
        'Bus' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
        'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
        'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
        'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
        'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
        'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
        'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
        'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
        'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
        'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
        'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
        'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
        'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
        'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
        'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
        'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
        'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
        'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
        'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
        'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
        'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
        'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
        'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
        'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'Str' => Illuminate\Support\Str::class,
        'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,

    ],

];
```

/config/cors.php

```
    return [

     /*
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     | Laravel CORS
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |
     | allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders and allowedMethods can be set to array('*')
     | to accept any value.
     |
     */
    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'], // ex: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT',  'DELETE']
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,
];
```

Kernel.php

```
  <?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,


    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The priority-sorted list of middleware.
     *
     * This forces non-global middleware to always be in the given order.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewarePriority = [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    ];
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return view('start');
});

Route::get('/home', function () {
    return view('home');
});
```

used this tut for cors set-up:
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

[image: response]

---

[image: console]

---

[image: console pt1]

Comment: My guess is you have not configured your Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (cors.php) correctly because your error is "has been blocked by CORS policy". I highly doubt the error is in the code you have posted.

Comment: Show your middleware where you have sent CORS headers. Also, using a front end framework like Vue in your blade file seems odd to me. You should have a separate Vue project and have Lumen(Laravel's micro framework) as the backend.

Comment: @Martin & rest, I edited my post and added my additional .php config files (don't wonder about both cors, I tried to use different provider)

Comment: @lafllamme did you solved your problem? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

check the message *Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It **does not have HTTP ok status**.*

This mean your option method is not responding 2xx status code. check if you dont have problems in the configuration of your API, and check if you have maintenance mode on the Laravel API.

Use `php artisan up` to disable maintenance mode.

Comment: I totally know what you mean, but I don't know how to achieve this. I edited my post with my cors.php & middleware - I hope this enlight this issue a little bit

Comment: @lafllamme This doesn't have to do with the CORS policy but that the Option is not responding 2xx, check the path storage/framework for a file name down. If there is the file, you have maintenance mode on.

Comment: Command gives out:"Application is already up." & storage/framework just contains .gitignore file including cache,sessions,testing,views folders

Comment: Can you open developer tools on you browser and give us the response of an endpoint, and the associated status code?

Comment: Check my post, I've added the console log

Comment: 404 status code on Option method, usually means that you are using a header that is not whitelisted. custom header (e.g. x-custom-header) but that header is not whitelisted in config.cors.headers or config.cors.additionalHeaders, Include Referer and check

Comment: I've edited config/cors.php (check post above) to accept any value, still the same => what shall I do? (u speak about options & whitelisting)

Comment: Im not an expert on the library you are using, and if its accepts placeholder * for headers, but what you have there seems logic. do you have on config/app.php Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class, instanced?

Comment: yes, inside the providers array I have :"        Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class" instanced.... I don't know where the issue is lol everything seems to be on the right place

Comment: The request failing is on that endpoint ip/api/forecast/PlayClient/sick_leavedays, that endpoint API is the one that you are modifying? or is another service, and we are doing nothing here?

Comment: it's the api that needs to get the data via POST, I checked it with Insomnia & Postman with success (no errors)

Comment: Postman/Insomnia are a developer tool, not a browser it doesn't control preflight request and CORS headers. so thats doesn't really help you too much, maybe you still have the problem there. If you have access to that API, create a get endpoint and check it via browser.

Answer (score 1):

you dont have CORS policy.

install this  "composer require spatie/laravel-cors" then put this middleware and the error will gone

```
// app/Http/Kernel.php

protected $middleware = [
...
\Spatie\Cors\Cors::class
];
```

Comment: I've already done this with two different cors providers - would u check my edited post?

Comment: @lafllamme Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Although I did not get the 404 error (which may be your first issue), i got the same "Response preflight ... status not ok" error.

In my case, the API Controller that handles the request was validating the request information. It checked for required informations using the validate function. As I did not post the required field in my request, the validation failed and the server did not respond with a HTTP status ok.

So you may check your API controller.

Answer (score 0):

The only solutions that comes to mind is putting the middleware Barry on top of the middlewares on the Kernel file...

Havent tried Spatie pack yet though, tell me if you manage...

also try to manage preflight... like two responses

```
if ($request->isMethod("OPTIONS")) {
            // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
            return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
           // return $response('');
        }
        //$request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');
        
        $response = $next($request);
```